# Rails 3 - 'Couldn't parse Yaml'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, psych

I don't know what I did wrong. I try to run 'rails c,' but it just gives me an error. It was working 10 minutes ago. :\

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 2
 column 12 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applic
ation/configuration.rb:88:in `database_configuration'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_r
ecord/base.rb:1904:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:32:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/railti
e.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/railti
e.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/railti
e.rb:180:in `load_console'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:154:in `block in load_console'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applic
ation/railties.rb:11:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applic
ation/railties.rb:11:in `all'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:154:in `load_console'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:26:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you show us the full backtrace?

Comment: Something worth noting: I can use rails c for another project, so it has to be related to my project.

Comment: I think, there is some problem in loading database settings from database yaml. verify your database.yml if it is valid

Comment: Can you post an answer? I can't seem to accept your comment.

Comment: Can you post your config/database.yml file, it looks like the problem is in that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack dump mentions database_configuration, so I'd start with your database.yml file.

```
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:88:in `database_configuration'
```

Comment: Can you post your config/database.yml file, it looks like the problem is in that file. – Rob Di Marco -- Please post this as an answer, I would like to accept your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this at the beginning of config/boot.rb

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for the record, YAML doesn't accept tabs as indentation, they must be spaces. Changing tabs to spaces solved it for me `^^`

Comment: This solved it for me on Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2.p280. Didn't have to use the 'syck' yaml parser.

Answer (score 2):

**"Couldn't parse Yaml"**
Go to your project and see near the project name there is a ! sign.open it and see in which file conflict occurred.right click that file,select Replace with then Latest from Repository.Do this for all the files u changed code.then run the server it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I issued this problem with an unquoted * in one of my YAML file.

```
fr:
  simple_form:
    yes: Oui
    no:  Non

    required:
      text: required
      mark: "*"
```

Hope it will help. :)