# After upgrading to rails 3.2 I see ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, yaml

I see the following error after upgrading to rails 3.2.12 with ruby 1.9.2.

> ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing /SampelRails/user_properties.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Please have a look at http://www.yaml.org/faq.html
>   The exact error was:
>     Psych::SyntaxError: couldn't parse YAML at line 1 column 0

I have doubled checked the yml files and they seem to be indented properly.

according to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2731 this issue seem to be fixed in rails 3.1.1.

Comment: If you just switched to 1.9.2: in 1.9.2. the YAML parser has changed, so that could explain it. Secondly, strings are by default utf-8, so that could also have an effect if you have some special (e.g. accented) characters in your YAML. But to be certain, it would help to see the smallest YAML file that gives you the error.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843104/rails-3-couldnt-parse-yaml?rq=1

Comment: tnx for the response .. the solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link posted by nathanvda really worked.

> Try adding this at the beginning of config/boot.rb

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
```

[Rails 3 - 'Couldn't parse Yaml'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843104/rails-3-couldnt-parse-yaml?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

just experienced the same issue but the problem was that i was saving my [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) cassettes in `test/fixtures/vcr_cassettes/*.yml`.
`ActiveRecord::Fixture` gets confused by yml files with content other than AR fixture data.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Solved it by removing a dummy fixture file from fixtures directory. That file had nothing but comments in it.