# ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixture

I 'm trying to make a of my first application on ruby ...
Thats's my test file

```
   require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

   class SupplierTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
        fixtures :suppliers
        def test_name
           supplier=Supplier.create(:name => 'juan' , :province => nil)
           assert_equal 'juan' , supplier.get_name
        end
   end
```

and the fixture

```
   juan: 
     id:1
     name:juan
     province:nil
```

and the result is

```
    Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning    a  simple key at line 8 column 1
```

Answer (score 1):

YAML requires a space between the `:` and the value, so try updating your fixture to:

```
juan: 
  id: 1
  name: juan
  province:
```

(writing `nil` in province will result in the value `"nil"`. Leaving it empty will result in a true `nil` value)

Comment: I 've cchanged the fixture adding the spaces bur now says  ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:

Comment: Double check that your YAML is properly formatted, if it is, check if maybe this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406670/after-upgrading-to-rails-3-2-i-see-activerecordfixtureformaterror-a-yaml-er

Comment: Check YAML syntax and correctness using any tool online or offline. Eg. yaml-online-parser.appspot.com

Comment: To explicitly express Ruby's `nil` in YAML, use [`null`](http://yaml.org/type/null.html).